# Accessing array of obejcts inside array

Tags: javascript, angular

I have below JSON return as response from API:

```
{"data":"123","value":[{name:'test", class:"A1"},{name:'test2", class:"A2"},{name:'test", class:"A3"}]}
```

I want to access name & class property of value array. 
I tried:

```
myArray.forEarch((element, index, array) => {

})
```

but this does not work well. Any pointer please.

Thankk

Comment: `myArray.forEarch` Spelling matters in programming. What is `myArray`? is that the object in your first code? (It's an object, not an array)

Comment: Assuming the response is parsed into an object (and is actually proper JSON, not the single quote mess in your question) and stored in `obj`, you need `obj.value.forEach((element, index) => { ... });`

Comment: The response also looks to be invalid JSON, it won't parse - the brackets are mismatched, and `'` string delimiters are forbidden in JSON (you must always use `"`)

Comment: my bad, but looks like I did that mistake as typo,thanks for pointing out anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a foreach like that.

```js
const data = {'data':'123','value':[{'name':'test', 'class':'A1'},{'name':'test2', 'class':'A2'},{'name':'test', 'class':'A3'}]}



data.value.forEach(function (el){ 
  console.log(el.name);
  console.log(el.class);
});
```

Comment: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined , I am getting this error

Comment: Can you send me your code? You must correct your JSON because it is incorrect. There is a mix of " and ', you have to use one or the other

Comment: data[0].value.map((el)=>{}) did the tweak, thanks for your help.

Comment: Great, have a nice day!

Answer (score -1):

Try this...

```
const jsonData = JSON.parse( ... );

for (const obj of jsonData.values) {
    const name = obj.name;
    const _class = obj.class;

    // Use name and _class
}
```